# python requests POST 400 error

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been looking to many questions similar to mine but I could not find a solution.

I'm using *requests* to perform a POST request. I've tried a lot of combinations inside the request but nothing returns a 201 ok.

Here is my code:

```
 import json
 import requests

 if __name__ == '__main__':

    headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
    url = "http://myserver/ext/v3.1/test_device"
    message = {"atribute_a": "value", "atribute_b": "valueb"}
    params = {"priority":"normal"}

    r = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(message) )
    print(r)
```

I've also tried withou json.dumps but it also gives me 400 bad request. I've also tried to add the params directly to the url like: *...?priority=normal* but with no success.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a comma between params and headers in requests.post?

Comment: yes @GauravOjha of course. I tested with a comma. just a bad copy&past

Comment: Did you try to use data = message directly instead of json.dumps?

Comment: Yes @GauravOjha. I said that after my code but thanks for trying to help me

Comment: This probably has to do with how your server is processing this request. Can you show what kind of request is being expected by your server?

Comment: @GauravOjha For example, I get 201 ok in the command line if I run: curl -vvv -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"atribute_a": "value", "atribute_b": false}' "http://myserver/ext/v3.1/test_device/?priority=normal"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments, your server is actually expecting data as a stringified JSON object.
As far as the params are concerned, it'd most probably help if they're declared as a tuple of tuples (or a dict of dicts)

Try the following -

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('priority', 'normal'),
)

data = {
    "atribute_a": "value",
    "atribute_b": false
}

requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, data=str(data))
```

Answer (score 19):

The easiest technique is to use `json` instead of `data` as followed:

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, json=data)
```